# randomized select not give steady solution

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

*EDIT*
try run in the main:

```
int[] arr = {646 ,94 ,366 ,754 ,948 ,678 ,121 ,320 ,528 ,36};
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   System.out.println(randomizedSelect(arr,0,arr.length-1,5));
   printArr(arr);
   }
```

and see that i got diffrent outpot in each loop..

Got a little problem that I would like some help with, if anyone knows how.
I need to find the k<sup>th</sup> smallest value in an array by randomized partition.
I've got two problems:

1. I get array out of bounds with -1 and can't find a way to fix it.
2. Most of the time it works but sometimes it gives me wrong *k* place.

For example for array with length of 10, it tells me that 20 is in the 5<sup>th</sup> place but actually it should be in the 2<sup>nd</sup> place and it prints the array where not all the values on the left are smaller than 20 and not smaller than the 5<sup>th</sup> place.

Here is an example array:

```
{646 ,94 ,366 ,754 ,948 ,678 ,121 ,320 ,528 ,36}
```

The array input is done by a random number generator.

This is my code:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nSize = askSizeN();
        int kSize = askSizeK(nSize);
        int[] arr = new int[nSize];
        chose(arr);
        int[] arrCopy = new int[nSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrCopy.length; i++) {
            arrCopy[i] = arr[i];
        }
        printArr(arrCopy);
        System.out.println(randomizedSelect(arrCopy, 0, arr.length - 1, kSize));
        printArr(arrCopy);
    }

    private static int partition(int[] arr, int p, int r) {
        int x = arr[r];
        int i = p - 1;
        for (int j = p; j < r; j++) {
            if (arr[j] <= x) {
                i++;
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        int temp = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = arr[r];
        arr[r] = temp;
        return i + 1;
    }

    private static int randomizedPartition(int[] arr, int p, int r) {
        int i = rand.nextInt(r - p);
        int temp = arr[r];
        arr[r] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
        return partition(arr, p, r);
    }

    private static int randomizedSelect(int[] arr, int p, int r, int i) {
        if (p == r) {
            return arr[p];
        }
        int q = randomizedPartition(arr, p, r);
        int k = q - p + 1;
        if (i == k) {
            return arr[q];
        }
        else if (i < k) {
            return randomizedSelect(arr, p, q - 1, i);
        }
        else {
            return randomizedSelect(arr, q + 1, r, i - k);
        }
    }

    private static int askSizeN() {
        System.out.println("Please chose the size of the heap: \n" + "(the size of n)");
        return scan.nextInt();
    }

    private static int askSizeK(int nSize) {
        System.out.println(
                "Please chose how much small values you want to see: \n" + "(the size of k)");
        int kSize = scan.nextInt();
        if (kSize > nSize) {
            System.out.println("cant print more number then the size of the Heap..");
            System.out.println("Please enter a number less then " + (nSize + 1));
            askSizeK(nSize);
        }
        return kSize;
    }

    private static int[] chose(int[] a) {
        System.out.println("Chose the option you want: \n" + "\t1. enter your own values."
                + "\n\t2. let me generate random values");
        int chose = scan.nextInt();
        if (chose == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter value number " + (i + 1));
                a[i] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
        else if (chose == 2) {
            System.out.println("Generate random numbers.");
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                a[i] = rand.nextInt(1000);
            }
        }
        else {
            chose(a);
        }
        return a;
    }

 private static void printArr(int[] a){
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know which line is giving the out of bounds error? usually a stack trace of the error says the line number as well.

Comment: You say that you have a problem printing the array but you didn't post the code of method `printArr`. Also, I copied and ran your code (I wrote a `printArr` method) and I couldn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Are you trying to do [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)?

Comment: really sorry, just edit and add the printArr method, its just a loop that print the array.
when i do for loop for the main method i got diffrent outpot thats my main problem.

Comment: try in the main run this insted and see that the output is change.

int[] arr = {646 ,94 ,366 ,754 ,948 ,36};
       for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
       System.out.println(randomizedSelect(arr,0,arr.length-1,3));
       printArr(arr);
       }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

Method `randmizedPartition()` was generating wrong *random pivot* for partition.

I solved it by changing the random line to:

```
int i = rand.nextInt((r - p) + 1) + p;
```